# iis7 web config file not working error hosting

Tags: iis, iis-7

I have been trying hard to fix the issue in the web.config which doesn't allow me to host my site in the iis 8.5 - windows 2012 r2, throws this error which i have attached a screen shot.

I have no clue of what is going wrong here.

If some one could just shed some light, much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Error message is pretty clear. Handler section is locked at parent or grand parent level. When section is locked at parent level you can not override it in child configuration.
Please check following web.config files at following locations.

1. Check if you have web.config file at location C:\intetpub\wwwroot. If its present check if you have following tag in web.config

   ```
   <section name="handlers" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
   ```

   If its there then change it to

   ```
   <section name="handlers" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
   ```
2. If you don't find web.config in #1 above then open applicationHost.config located at path C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config
   Check if you have handler section with overrideModeDefault="Deny" and if it is then change it to overrideModeDefault="Allow" as shown in #1.
   Once you change it overrideModeDefault="Allow" then you can override it in child web.config